# How to inspect file permissions served by Karma

Tags: javascript, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, karma-webpack

I'm new to Karma. When I run *npx karma start* I see the following gets triggered:

```
http://localhost:9876/
http://localhost:9876/socket.io/socket.io.js
http://localhost:9876/karma.js
http://localhost:9876/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MyKpKbk
http://localhost:9876/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MyKpKc7&sid=lMjFEd1O8LUrK32-AAAB
http://localhost:9876/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MyKpKc8&sid=lMjFEd1O8LUrK32-AAAB
ws://localhost:9876/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=lMjFEd1O8LUrK32-AAAB // returns a 101 switching protocols message
http://localhost:9876/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MyKpKdy&sid=lMjFEd1O8LUrK32-AAAB
http://localhost:9876/context.html
http://localhost:9876/context.js
http://localhost:9876/esm-test-loader.js
```

All of these calls are successful. However, the next file it attempts to load gets rejected by my corporate proxy:

```
http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/source-map-support/browser-source-map- 
support.js?d5ed9cabce4cb9162440415eea7e8484e51d1aea
```

Can the permissions be different from my local machine to the local server where the files are served? How can I check the permissions on localhost?

Comment: We don't do "SOLVED" here. If you found your answer either close your question or post the answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

When you have *http_proxy* and *https_proxy* defined as environment variables then this error will occur. The fix is to add a new environment variable *NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1*. This bug killed me for days. I hope it helps someone.